# Memory leak in Gin Gonic webserver?

Tags: go, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, rss, go-gin

### Description

I've encountered a potential memory leak in the gin-gonic/gin web server. I have tried replicating the issue by creating a simple /health_check endpoint. The endpoint /health_check is hit every second. The issue results in an out-of-memory (OOM) condition when when the available pod memory is exhausted. There is no other container running in the pod.

I have also exposed pprof and prometheus metrics to understand the issue, but could not find anything. Don't see any other listed issues reporting the same, so I was hoping someone could help me isolate the issue.

I don't see any increase in heap or stack memory, but the process memory keeps increasing. I can see the increase using RSS and corresponding memory block using pmap, but I am not able to trace why the memory doesn't clear or what that allocated memory is used for.

### How to reproduce

Simple code example with relevant endpoints:

```golang
package server

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    _ "net/http/pprof"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp"
)

func setupRouter() *gin.Engine {
    router := gin.New()
    router.GET("/health_check", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello World!")
    })
    router.GET("/debug/pprof", gin.WrapF(http.DefaultServeMux.ServeHTTP))
    router.GET("/debug/pprof/:pprofType", gin.WrapF(http.DefaultServeMux.ServeHTTP))
    router.GET("/metrics", func(c *gin.Context) {
        handler := promhttp.Handler()
        handler.ServeHTTP(c.Writer, c.Request)
    })

    return router
}

func Start() {
    router := setupRouter()
    err := router.Run(":8080")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error starting server: %v\n", err)
    }
}
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "example.com/health-check/server"
)

func main() {
    server.Start()
}
```

Build Command:

```
go build -ldflags="-s -w" -race -o health-check main.go
```

Pod Resource Limits:

1. 64MiB Memory
2. 1 CPU

### Expectations

I expected a consistent memory usage. Some fluctuations are fine, but I expect the memory usage to mostly be consistent and not run Out Of Memory.

### Actual result

The Pod crashed predictably due to continuous memory increase in roughly 90 mins by OOM. Each spike in the below image indicates a pod restart because of OOM.

[image: Gin Server Pod Restarts]

[image: Go Metrics Resident Memory]

[image: Pod Restart Counter]

[image: Heap and Stack Usage]

Goroutines

```
goroutine 8334 [running]:
runtime/pprof.writeGoroutineStacks({0x7f0e9e220b20, 0xc000506200})
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/pprof/pprof.go:703 +0x75
runtime/pprof.writeGoroutine({0x7f0e9e220b20, 0xc000506200}, 0x2)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/pprof/pprof.go:692 +0x45
runtime/pprof.(*Profile).WriteTo(0x1509f00, {0x7f0e9e220b20, 0xc000506200}, 0xc?)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/pprof/pprof.go:329 +0x1b1
net/http/pprof.handler.ServeHTTP({0xc000051601, 0x9}, {0x7f0e5462fd18, 0xc000506200}, 0x0?)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/pprof/pprof.go:267 +0x58a
net/http/pprof.Index({0x7f0e5462fd18?, 0xc000506200}, 0xc000506600)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/pprof/pprof.go:384 +0x129
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xf53ac8, {0x7f0e5462fd18, 0xc000506200}, 0xc0000b0500?)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2136 +0x48
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0xc0004a3740?, {0x7f0e5462fd18, 0xc000506200}, 0xc000506600)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2514 +0xbd
example.com/health-check/server.setupRouter.WrapF.func4(0xc000506200)
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.9.1/utils.go:42 +0x97
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(*Context).Next(...)
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.9.1/context.go:174
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(*Engine).handleHTTPRequest(0xc0001871e0, 0xc000506200)
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.9.1/gin.go:620 +0xb91
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(*Engine).ServeHTTP(0xc0001871e0, {0x105b2e0?, 0xc00027e540}, 0xc000506600)
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.9.1/gin.go:576 +0x425
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP({0xc000600db0?}, {0x105b2e0, 0xc00027e540}, 0xc000506600)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2938 +0x2a2
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc000240900, {0x105c478, 0xc0001ad5c0})
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2009 +0xc25
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve in goroutine 1
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:3086 +0x80d

goroutine 1 [IO wait]:
internal/poll.runtime_pollWait(0x7f0e9ea9d410, 0x72)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:343 +0x85
internal/poll.(*pollDesc).wait(0xc0003a62a0, 0x4ae001?, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:84 +0xb1
internal/poll.(*pollDesc).waitRead(...)
    /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:89
internal/poll.(*FD).Accept(0xc0003a6280)
    /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:611 +0x405
net.(*netFD).accept(0xc0003a6280)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:172 +0x3e
net.(*TCPListener).accept(0xc00024d480)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go:152 +0x3e
net.(*TCPListener).Accept(0xc00024d480)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/tcpsock.go:315 +0x65
net/http.(*Server).Serve(0xc00054c000, {0x105b520, 0xc00024d480})
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:3056 +0x57f
net/http.(*Server).ListenAndServe(0xc00054c000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2985 +0xbd
net/http.ListenAndServe(...)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:3239
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(*Engine).Run(0xc0001871e0, {0xc0003bbef8, 0x1, 0x1})
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.9.1/gin.go:386 +0x38d
example.com/health-check/server.Start()
    /app/server/server.go:49 +0x52
main.main()
    /app/main.go:8 +0x1d

goroutine 82 [IO wait]:
internal/poll.runtime_pollWait(0x7f0e9ea9d318, 0x72)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:343 +0x85
internal/poll.(*pollDesc).wait(0xc0002c60a0, 0xc000568000?, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:84 +0xb1
internal/poll.(*pollDesc).waitRead(...)
    /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:89
internal/poll.(*FD).Read(0xc0002c6080, {0xc000568000, 0x1000, 0x1000})
    /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:164 +0x3e5
net.(*netFD).Read(0xc0002c6080, {0xc000568000, 0x1000, 0x1000})
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_posix.go:55 +0x4b
net.(*conn).Read(0xc000514010, {0xc000568000, 0x1000, 0x1000})
    /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:179 +0xad
net/http.(*connReader).Read(0xc0002c4450, {0xc000568000, 0x1000, 0x1000})
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:791 +0x2b5
bufio.(*Reader).fill(0xc000536d20)
    /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:113 +0x29a
bufio.(*Reader).Peek(0xc000536d20, 0x4)
    /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:151 +0xc7
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc0002e21b0, {0x105c478, 0xc0001ad5c0})
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2044 +0xe7c
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve in goroutine 1
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:3086 +0x80d

goroutine 8335 [IO wait]:
internal/poll.runtime_pollWait(0x7f0e9ea9d128, 0x72)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:343 +0x85
internal/poll.(*pollDesc).wait(0xc0002c62a0, 0xc000600dc1?, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:84 +0xb1
internal/poll.(*pollDesc).waitRead(...)
    /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:89
internal/poll.(*FD).Read(0xc0002c6280, {0xc000600dc1, 0x1, 0x1})
    /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:164 +0x3e5
net.(*netFD).Read(0xc0002c6280, {0xc000600dc1, 0x1, 0x1})
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_posix.go:55 +0x4b
net.(*conn).Read(0xc0000b04d0, {0xc000600dc1, 0x1, 0x1})
    /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:179 +0xad
net/http.(*connReader).backgroundRead(0xc000600db0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:683 +0x83
created by net/http.(*connReader).startBackgroundRead in goroutine 8334
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:679 +0x246
```

### Environment

- go version: go1.21.1 linux/amd64
- docker image: [1.21.1-bullseye](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/golang/1.21.1-bullseye/images/sha256-ca9ceec0316fe0f1f3f067721ed59637f2f823dc21ed4c9e47ffa527a9d3d026?context=explore)
- gin version (or commit ref): github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.9.1
- operating system: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
- GOGC=10;GOMEMLIMIT=64MiB (tried with default values as well, but same result)

Any help or guidance is appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: I have posted it as an issue in gin-gonic GitHub repo as well https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/3789

Comment: Did you set/experiment with GoGC and GOMEMLIMIT? If not: Why not?

Comment: just checked my api(did 200 requests), i have a healt_chech endpoint as well, after 2min the mem drops back to normal, so i dont thing its a gin issue

Comment: Note that actual memory leaks are _highly_ unlikely in Go.

Comment: Hello @Volker Thanks for the comment, I had tested with the default GOGC and GOMEMLIMIT after which I set GOGC=10 and set GOMEMLIMIT to 64MiB (the result was the same), but I will run a few more experiments and add the results here for ref. I will restrict the GOMEMLIMIT a but more and see what happens.

Comment: @GreenChicken can you please share your setup once? I was curious where you were testing? Was it in a kubernetes cluster or locally? Any other details will also be helpful, thanks a lot.

Comment: the api is on a kubernetes cluster, made a cron job that hits the endpoint every second, the memory usage jumped from 13mb to 21mb, and 2min after the last request it dropped back down to 13mb

Comment: @Volker I'm curious as to what makes you believe that memory leaks are "highly unlikely" in Go... The occurrence of repeated goroutine leaks (e.g. during the execution of a HTTP handler) is not uncommon and will often manifest itself as a memory leak. Memory leaks can also result from inappropriate re-slicing of an ever growing slice, thereby preventing the now inaccessible elements of the backing array from being GC'd; here's [a recent example from the standard library](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/54728).

Comment: So I tried various experiments with GOGC/GOMEMLIMIT, no matter what I set, it doesn't seem to have any impact, the memory seems to be growing pretty consistently. There is no impact on the heap, so I don't think these params are coming into play, only the RSS is increasing. And the only requests I am serving are /health_check and /metrics for prometheus.
I tried replicating this behaviour locally (using docker-compose) but couldn't. I will push that in a new repo and share for ref. I am staring to suspect that there is something wrong with my kubernetes deployment, but don't know for sure.

Comment: @jub0bs While its easy to leak goroutines and thus leaking _also_ memory it's really hard to leak memory _alone_. And it's unlikely that things like goroutine leaks in gin _itself_ are present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was running some experiments to figure out from where the memory was increasing.

I tried testing without the `-race` build flag, and the memory seems to be fine now. I don't see it increasing continuously on an idle server (serving only liveness, readiness probes and metrics endpoint).

I am not entirely sure why this is happening or if this is expected, but I will look more into it, and have removed the flag for now from our production deployments.

Sharing the memory trends after removing this flag (build command being `go build`), the spikes are load tests that I was running, firing 1M requests (100 in parallel at a time):

Following is the pod memory usage:
[image: Pod Memory Usage]

Following is the RSS:
[image: RSS]

Following is the Heap and Stack memory usage:
[image: Heap and Stack]

PS: I am marking this as the answer for now, but please feel free to correct me, I am still pretty new at golang, thanks a lot to everyone for contributing. If I find anything contrary to this result down the line I will update/remove this answer, thanks.

Comment: Here is the reference for golang race_detector overhead
https://go.dev/doc/articles/race_detector